# imread() stopped working on Octave

Tags: image, octave, graphicsmagick

I've tried googling it and it seems nobody else has had this kind of error.

I'm using Octave 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I've been using the imread() funcion to read images for quite some time, but just yesterday it started throwing this error:

```
octave:5> I = imread('example.jpg');
error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Unable to open file (tures/example.jpg) reported by coders/jpeg.c:955 (ReadJPEGImage)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.1/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7
```

If I try to read a PNG, I get a similar error:

```
octave:5> I = imread('example.png');
error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Unable to open file (tures/example.png) reported by coders/png.c:2790 (ReadPNGImage)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.1/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7
```

Does anybody know what's happening? How to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried re-installing either the image processing package you're using or else octave? Did this error start appearing after you installed something?

Comment: I tried reinstalling everything and the problem persists. I believe it probably started after one of Ubuntu's daily updates...

Comment: And is example.jpg etc definitely in the right folder? What is the path of your script and the path of the image?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with `3.6.4` on `Windows 8.1`, the simple workaround for me was this:

```
IMAGE_PATH = ('C:\Users\...');
```

where the image is stored

```
Image = file_in_path(IMAGE_PATH, 'image.jpg');
```

Of course it would be better to fix the actual function, but for now it's good enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Octave uses GraphicsMagick (or ImageMagick) to handle the reading and writing of images. GraphicsMagick does not handle directly the reading and writing of images, it's a wrapper for the many format libraries under a single API.

When you build GraphicsMagick, it checks your system for available libraries and disables/activates formats as those are presents. You probably built GraphicsMagick yourself without the development libraries libpng and libjpeg. In Ubuntu, I believe those are in the packages `libpng12-dev` and `libjpeg8-dev`. Either use the GraphicsMagick libraries that come with your system or if you need to build it yourself, see the instructions in the [Octave wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick).

To confirm this is indeed your problem, run `gm -version` and check if those formats are activated. For example, the output in my system shows:

```
Feature Support:
  Thread Safe              yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  no
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     yes
  JPEG-2000                yes
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               yes
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   yes (201107)
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WMF                      yes
  X11                      yes
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes
```

Comment: When I run 'gm -version', it seems like there's nothing wrong; both png and jpeg formats are marked as supported.
I tried reinstalling Octave, GraphicsMagick, building it on my own like the wiki does, and the problem persists.

Comment: @user3166406 double check that you don't have more than one GraphicsMagick around in your system. Or that you have more than one version of Octave and you're still running the previous Octave build (the one linked with the "bad" GraphicsMagick).